# assign a value to checkbox in a grid in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following grid in asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDWlocations" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" runat="server" GridLines="None" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
    EmptyDataText="No data found..." AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" Visible="true">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="allDWlocchk" runat="server" Checked="true" Width="10px" onclick="CheckAllgrdReqDW(this)"></asp:CheckBox>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_DWlocReq" runat="server" Checked="true" Width="5px" OnCheckedChanged="chk_Req_CheckedChangedDW_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_DWCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ml_loc_cd") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_DWDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Ml_loc_desc") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to assign value for "chk_DWlocReq" in code behind

like this

```
foreach (GridViewRow dgvr in grdDWlocations.Rows)
{
    (CheckBox)dgvr.FindControl("chk_DWlocReq")=true;                                                 
}
```

but above one not valid, how can this do properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your code must be changed to:

```
foreach (GridViewRow dgvr in grdDWlocations.Rows)
{
    ((CheckBox)dgvr.FindControl("chk_DWlocReq")).Checked=true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
    foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
        if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            CheckBox myCheckBoxID = row.FindControl("myCheckBoxID") as CheckBox;
        }
        myCheckBoxID.Checked = true;
    }
```

OR
If you are handling RowDataBound event, it's like this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox myCheckBoxID = e.Row.FindControl("myCheckBoxID") as CheckBox;
        }
        myCheckBoxID.Checked = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
CheckBox checkbox1 = dgvr.FindControl("chk_DWlocReq") as CheckBox;     
checkbox1.Checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
ds1.SelectCommand = String.Format("exec myStoredproc");
dv1 = (DataView)ds1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dv1.Table.Rows[i]["ReceiveNotification"].ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("GV_chkNotification")).Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("GV_chkNotification")).Checked = false;
                    }
    
                }
```